# copy file from one folder to another folder using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to upload a file using kendoUI upload.
and i am working in modular way , so i want to  copy a file from one folder to another folder by only using javascript rather than uploading files using server side code.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Copying files using JavaScript isn't supported by any browser as far as I know.